# Combine Forms Authentication with Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

A client wants to allow both AD users and non-AD users access to a SharePoint site. I have done similar work before on a ASP.NET site but that required a custom `MembershipProvider`.

Is there a way to do that with SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. SharePoint 2010 supports the FBA authentication in the claims authentication mode. Here's the good guide to enable it with ASP.NET standard SQL membership and role providers: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx. And note that by default the Windows authentication in the claims mode is turned on so you can mix FBA and Windows authentications.